# singularities( Essential and removable) of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have some doubts on this question. 
I think the first and second are false. As for the others I'm not sure.

Comment: The first one is clearly true.

Comment: you are right. i meant the second and fourth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the first one is true: if the Laurent series of $f$ at $z_0$ has infinitely many non-zero terms of the type $a_n(z-z_0)^n$ with $n<0$, then the same thing occurs with $(z-z_0)^2f(z)$.

But you are right about the secnd one: it is false.

The third one is true: you are multiplying $f(z)$ by an analytic function whose domain contains $z_0$: Therefore, the essential singularity at $z_0$ remains as such.

And the fourth one is false, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I meant that the second and fourth are false (my bad).